# Удаление последнего символа в MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace

Добрый день! Возник вопрос, как удалить последний символ (при условии, что этот символ - пробел) в строке (база MySQL)?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [`rtrim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim) вам не подходит?